# Magento 2 add block with js then call it from cms

Tags: magento2, javascript, blocks, phtml

I have simple code

```
<div class="container">
<h1>count</h1>

<div class="timer"></div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="circular-countdown.js"></script>

<script>
$('.timer').circularCountDown({
  size: 500,
  borderSize: 10,
  colorCircle: 'gray',
  background: 'white',
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  fontColor: '#333333',
  fontSize: 16,
  delayToFadeIn: 0,
  delayToFadeOut: 0,
  reverseLoading: false,
  reverseRotation: false,
  duration: {
      hours: 0,
      minutes: 0,
      seconds: 1000
  },
  beforeStart: function(){},
  end: function(){}
});
</script>
```

and try to show this counter in front-end . I create count.phtml in app/design/frontend/vendorname/module/Magento_Theme/templates/html

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Test</h1>
<div class="timer"></div>
</div>
<script>
$('.timer').circularCountDown({
  size: 500,
  borderSize: 10,
  colorCircle: 'gray',
  background: 'white',
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  fontColor: '#333333',
  fontSize: 16,
  delayToFadeIn: 0,
  delayToFadeOut: 0,
  reverseLoading: false,
  reverseRotation: false,
  duration: {
      hours: 0,
      minutes: 0,
      seconds: 1000
  },
  beforeStart: function(){},
  end: function(){}
});
</script>
```

then edit layout file default_head_blocks.xml and add

```
<script src="circular-countdown.js"></script>
```

after that I call this block from CMS:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="count_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/count.phtml"}}
```

script not run, I understand i cant run script from .phtml file directly so what i should do ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find issue with trying to run these files in the head of the page. Magento 2 is very picky about javascript load order, and in many cases wont load your scripts correctly. This will lead to endless amounts of console error. Mostly "jquery is not defined..." but there are loads others that will be kicked.

You are much better off using the built in require js system to loaded your scripts. I assume you are using [this circular js module](https://github.com/sygmaa/CircularCountDownJs/blob/master/circular-countdown.js), but any js module should work in the same way. Download this file and place it in your theme:

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/web/js/circular-countdown.js

You will need to wrap the code in a `define` statement like this:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function($) {

    // the code for the js module goes here

    };
    return CircularCountDown;
});
```

From there you want to set up a require js config file for easy and reliable use in your theme:

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js

with this code in it:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            circularCountDown: 'Magento_Theme/js/circular-countdown'
        }
    }
};
```

You will notice that the path defined here is the same as the file you placed above, omitting the `web` directory and the `.js` on the end of the file. Why? I don't know, it's just the Magento convention and a way to keep end users guessing at what the hell they were thinking when they did this. But all the same, you are now free to set up a template and run the JS in conjunction with the html markup:

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/circular.phtml

with this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class="timer" style="min-height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'circularCountDown',
        'domReady!'
    ], function($) {
        $('.timer').circularCountDown({
            size: 200,
            borderSize: 10,
            colorCircle: 'gray',
            background: 'white',
            fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
            fontColor: '#333333',
            fontSize: 16,
            delayToFadeIn: 0,
            delayToFadeOut: 0,
            reverseLoading: false,
            reverseRotation: false,
            duration: {
                hours: 0,
                minutes: 0,
                seconds: 60
            },
            beforeStart: function(){},
            end: function(){}
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that i did change a few things for my testing, but what you want to take away from this is the use of the `require` and the passing in of the needed files `jquery`, `circularCountDown` and `domReady!`. Without `domReady!` i was getting `circularCountDown is not a function errors` so it's worth keeping around. This template is now ready to get used anywhere it's called on the site. For my testing i just called it into the homepage.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="count_file" template="Magento_Theme::circular.phtml"}}
```

[image]

Comment: Great look like we on right track . I test it and white screen show under title so you test it ?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? If there are no errors, and the footer is not loading on the page (i.e. you see the "test" and under that you have nothing) it sounds like a php/xml error. Odds are good that you don't have an error in the code we are using (not much php or xml here) but that cache or compilation is playing havoc on the page.

Comment: I'm posing a screen shot from what i'm getting on the local site i'm testing on in my answer.

Comment: can you send me js file with define ?

Comment: I get in last line (jQuery)); - expected ) and intead saw ';' missing semicolon

Comment: Nice! is it working for you now?

Comment: No still not working

Comment: I mean may be i have problem with circular-countdown.js file

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5oOgJp check line 247 (jQuery)); - expected ) and intead saw ';' missing semicolon

Comment: I see the issue, here is the way you want to set up that file: https://github.com/circlesix/magento_22_learning/blob/master/app/design/frontend/CustomerParadigm/theme/Magento_Theme/web/js/circular-countdown.js

Comment: All things done now, Thanks This is a very useful answer .

Comment: Sweet, glad we got this working for you!

Comment: I have custom module and want manage this counter from it, only add button to reset count . I understand how add admin manage section, etc... to module but can i get your idea what should i do for this button ?.

Comment: It might be worth asking that in a new question. It will be hard to work through that in the comments of this one. link back to here when you post is and more people can help out and follow along.

Comment: yes, you are right will do and mention you here . Thanks

Comment: Pls check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213132/magento-2-counter-reset-from-admin

Comment: I put together a little module based on the user that responded to this post, should be good enough to get you where you need to go. https://github.com/circlesix/magento_22_learning/tree/master/app/code/CustomerParadigm/Countdown

Answer (score 0):

You should add the **js** file plus the **library** in your current theme inside `default_head_blocks.xml`, with this xml you files will be loaded in all pages !

**app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js" src_type="url" />
        <script src="Magento_Theme::js/circular-countdown.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

You get your phtml in cms page like this:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/count.phtml"}}
```

your phtml should inside : **app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/count.phtml**

Comment: Thanks I try Mr circlesix solution and working with me .

Comment: what about cms block?